# -g option ignored when building c++ programs with "make"

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, makefile, gdb

Unfortunately I can't remember when this first occurred, but recently I've noticed a strange bug when I run "make" to build a program.

The I have the following makefile:

```
SOURCE = Foo.cpp \
         Foobar.cpp

OBJECTS = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
LIBS = -lX11 -lGL -lGLU

program: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o platform

.o: .cpp
    g++ -g -c $@
```

Annoyingly, when I run make I get:

```
$ make
g++    -c -o Foo.o Foo.cpp
g++    -c -o Foobar.o Foobar.cpp
g++ Foo.o Foobar.o -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -o program
```

The "-g" option being ignored.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  Interestingly I tried manually typing the commands in the terminal:

```
$ g++ -g -c Foo.cpp
$ g++ -g -c Foobar.cpp
$ make
g++ Foo.o Foobar.o -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -o program
```

And it works as intended and I can use programs like gdb correctly, so it doesn't seem to be a C++/gcc problem,  I'm not hugely experienced with makefiles but none of the examples or tutorials I've read seem to have any problem with disappearing options and there don't seem to be any posts about it.  Did I just do something stupid and not realize it?

Comment: It might be using built-in compile rules instead of yours (though I can't immediately see why). Try setting `CPPFLAGS=-g` or `CFLAGS`

Comment: In case you didn't notice (and it appears you didn't), `-g` isn't being ignored. The *rule* is. Do you not also see there is no `-o` in your rule body, but there is in your output? The default rule is being used.

Comment: Wrong: `.o: .cpp`.  Better:  `%.o: %.cpp`.  Here's a good [makefile tutorial](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

Comment: Since the built-in rule is doing its job correctly, I'm half-inclined say just go with Rup's suggestion and modify CPPFLAGS and CFLAGS, which *are* picked up by the built-in rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule to build the object files is wrong, it is missing the `%`:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -g -c $<
```

Comment: I think `$@` should be `$<`...?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working either.  I copied you suggestion verbatim and got this: 'g++ -g -c Main.o
g++: error: Main.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
'

Comment: Thanks Joachim! the problem was $<